# Bottom of Pop Up Form is not fully showing the back ground color

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling to get the CSS to do what I would like to see in the pop up (which displays a form ) that I am using but the bottom of the pop up form is still not showing all the white background.

The CSS is below with the form that sits inside the pop up.  What am I doing wrong and how do I correct this annoyance?

```js
   SectionDefinedByColumns.onclick =function (event){ 
   window.section_name=document.getElementById('SectionDefinedByColumns').value;   
   console.log( section_name )
   document.getElementById("popupColumnDefinitionForm").style.display = "block"; 
   document.getElementById('CurrentTextArea').value="";
        }
        
        function AddColumnDefinitionForm(){
 //
 //   Get the column number, number of plots, the order and the start plot number
 //
        var CurrentDefinition = document.getElementById('CurrentTextArea').value; 
        var ColumnNumber= document.getElementById('column').value;
        var NumberOfPlots= document.getElementById('plots').value;
        var OrderOfPlots= document.getElementById('columnorder').value;
        var NumberPlotsBy= document.getElementById('columnnumberingorder').value;
        var StartWithPlot= document.getElementById('startplot').value;
        console.log(CurrentDefinition,ColumnNumber,NumberOfPlots,OrderOfPlots,StartWithPlot);
        document.getElementById('CurrentTextArea').value=CurrentDefinition.concat 
        (section_name,",","by_columns",",",ColumnNumber,",",
        NumberOfPlots,",",       
        OrderOfPlots,",",
        NumberPlotsBy,",",
        StartWithPlot,";");
        
        }
        
    
     function DoneColumnDefinitionForm(frm){
 //
 //  Get the entire set of column definitions and pass it as a hidden type for retreival by the original form
 //
        var CurrentColumnDefinition = document.getElementById('CurrentTextArea').value; 
        var newHidInp = document.createElement('input');        
        newHidInp.type  = 'hidden';
        newHidInp.name  = 'SectionDefinition';      
        newHidInp.value = CurrentColumnDefinition;
        document.getElementById("process_canvas").appendChild(newHidInp);
//        frm.appendChild(newHidInp);
        console.log(CurrentColumnDefinition);
        document.getElementById("popupColumnDefinitionForm").style.display = "none";  // clear the pop up
//        return true;

        }
        
        function CloseColumnDefinitionForm() {
        
        document.getElementById("popupColumnDefinitionForm").style.display = "none";  // clear the pop up
        
        }
```

```css
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    
      }
      .openBtn {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
      }
      .openButton {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #1c87c9;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: fixed;
      }
      .loginPopup {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .formPopup {
        display: none;
         max-height: 340px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 45%;
        top: 5%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
        border: 3px solid #999999;
        z-index: 9;
        opacity: 1.0;
      }
      .formContainer {
         max-width: 1600px;
         max-height: 350px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        
      }
   
      .formContainer .btn {
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #8ebf42;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 30%;
  
        opacity: 1.0;
      }
      .formContainer .cancel {
        background-color: #cc0000;
      }
      .formContainer .btn:hover,
      .openButton:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      
      .boxed {
  border: 1px solid green ;
}
```

```html
<div class="formPopup" id="popupColumnDefinitionForm">
        <form class="formContainer">

          <label for="definecolumns">
            <strong>Please define section map by columns:</strong>
          </label>
            <br><br>
           <label for="columns"  style="font-size: 15px;">Column Number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="column" name="column_number" style="width: 3em; height:18px;" >
            <br><br>
            
           <label for="numberofcolumn" style="font-size: 15px;">Number of plots:</label>
            <input type="number" id="plots" name="number_of_plots" style="width: 3em; " >
            
           <label for="order" style="font-size: 15px;">Order by:</label>
            <select id="order" name="columnorder">
              <option value="top_to_bottom" selected>Top to bottom </option>
              <option value="bottom_to_top"  >Bottom to top </option>   
            </select>
           
           <label for="order" style="font-size: 15px;">Number from:</label>
            <select id="columnnumbering" name="columnnumberorder">
              <option value="left_to_right" selected>Left to right </option>
              <option value="right_to_left"  >Right to Left </option>   
            </select>
            
            
           <label for="columnStart" style="font-size: 15px;">Start with Plot:</label>
            <input type="text" id="startplot" name="startwithplot"  style="width: 7em; font-size: 15px; ">
          
          <br>  
          
          <label for="definecolumns">
            <strong>Defined Section Map by Columns:</strong>
          </label>
          <br>
          <textarea name="definedsectioncolumns" disabled id="CurrentTextArea" cols="50" rows="5" style="overflow:auto;resize:none" >""</textarea>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="AddColumnDefinitionForm()">Add another column</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="DoneColumnDefinitionForm(this)">Done</button>  
        
          <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="CloseColumnDefinitionForm()">Cancel</button>
        

        </form>

      </div>
```

Comment: Hi can you include your JS as well?

Comment: John,  where can I include the JS code.  Comment limits me to how many characters I can put in.

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ and post a link to it?

Comment: John - I posted on fiddle.net  at  https://jsfiddle.net/dhavqmLu/

Comment: Ok great. I edited your question so it has all the code on here.

Comment: Can you explain the issue a little further? I removed `display: none;` from `.formPopup` on here and I see an all white background https://jsfiddle.net/dhavqmLu/  What should it be?

Comment: The code (CSS and JS) is part of a PHP based code that I developed.   When I click on the first form (which I did not share with you) it launces the form in a pop up.  The form that pops up shows about 5 pixels at the bottom of the green background while the rest is white.   I would like the entire pop up form to be white.  I did what you suggested and it did not work

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or something? I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: Actually, I have a hunch of what might be your problem.  Try adding `height: 100%;` to `.formPopup` and let me know if that solved your issue.

Comment: John - where should I post the screen shot?

Comment: Jack, try the height thing first in my last comment and let me know if that fixed it.  If not, you can add the screenshot to imgur.com and post a link to it here.

Comment: I added  ` height: 100%;` to .formPopup   and did not remove display: none;    The problem is still showing.  I placed the HTML and CSS on jsfiddle

Comment: I placed the screen shot here:  https://imgur.com/recpDCl

Comment: Is this site live yet? Can you link to the page? I'm not able to replicate your issue with the code you've provided.

Comment: John -   The site is not released as it is still under development,  Give me until the end of the week to put something together that demonstrates the issue.   Thanks for all your help.

Comment: John - I got ambitious and created a test set up for you at  http://18.191.199.210/TestUI/index.php    Select Design Section Map >  By Columns or By Rows.   I just noticed that on my 17" laptop up shows up as a problem but on my wife's 15" laptop it does not show up as a problem. Could this be the smoking gun of where the issue is in the CSS specifications?

Comment: try adding that `height: 100%;` to `.formContainer` in CSS. Also To make it better, remove `border: 3px solid #999999;` from `.formpopup` and move it to `.formContainer`

Comment: Also try removing the `max-height` from `formContainer` as well as removing `height:100%` from `.formpopup`

Comment: John - That did the trick.  I really appreciate your help.  Thank you.  This issue is closed.

Comment: Fantastic, glad to have helped.